# How to word two items together compared to a separate item?

Tags: word-choice, punctuation

Consider the following example: "there is a relationship between cats and dogs and bears". How can this be punctuated/worded so that it is clear that the comparison is between [cats and dogs] and [bears]?

Comment: You could rearrange your sentence: "Cats and dogs have a relationship with bears."

Comment: Thanks, but that won't really work. The text should indicate a relationship found in data, like a statistical relationship, not just similarity.

Comment: Well it depends on your context, but you might try something like "The data show that cats and dogs have a relationship with bears". Again it depends on your context though, so that might not work.

Comment: It's not a very good example, since obviously there is also a relationship between cats and dogs, between dogs and bears, etc. Better would be something like *There is one big difference between cats and dogs and dolphins*. But even that could be interpreted ambiguously, by someone who was thinking in terms of which animal to use for ***D*** in an "illustrated alphabet for children".

Comment: "The relationship cats and dogs have with bears can be shown..."?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks, but, again, I think that suggests more actual similarity than statistical relatedness.

Comment: @Susan -  I just tried shuffling around the sentence as per your example. Actually: "The relationship cats and dogs have to bears...". Thanks! Still interested in others' suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen *[vis-à-vis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vis-%C3%A0-vis#Preposition)* used in such contexts.  Eg:

> There is a relationship of cats and dogs vis-à-vis bears.

I think the intended meaning then is quite clear, but perhaps some sticklers will find fault with the construction, perceiving it as redundant.  (*Vis-à-vis* means “in relation to; compared with”.)

Comment: 'versus' is a bit less exotic and also works.